# Get not undefined items from array in javascript ES5

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-5

I'm retrieving a list of items from the server side in JSON format and storing them into a javascript array. The list of items retrieved from the server can contain duplicate elements but I need that the javascript array only contains unique elements.

In order to do that, I'm using the `id` field from each item (an integer value) as the array index, so that I can check if the item is already in the array by checking the array value at that position.

Due to that the resulting array can contain only elements at indexes 0 and 5 (just an example), and I'm facing problems when iterating it with jQuery's `$.each()` method, because it traverses every array position from 0 to 5, being `undefined` the values in positions 1-4.

I can of course just check that the item is not undefined when traversing, but I would like to know if there is some native or straightforward way to obtain the values of the array from those positions that aren't undefined.

```
var x = [];
x[0] = "some value";
x[5] = "another value";

$.each(x, function(index, value) {
   console.log(index + " - " + value);    
});

// This results in:
// 0 - some value
// 1 - undefined
// 2 - undefined
// 3 - undefined
// 4 - undefined
// 5 - another value
```

I also accept suggestions to perform this process in a different way, instead of using the item id as the array index to check uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Use an object instead:

```js
var x = {};
x[0] = "some value";
x[5] = "another value";

$.each(x, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + " - " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Reasonable solution if they don't need any of the other array features.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array's own [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which skips non-existent entries:

```js
var x = [];
x[0] = "some value";
x[5] = "another value"
x.forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log(index + " - " + value);
});
```

Note that the order of the parameters to the callback is reversed.

If you really want to use `$.each`, do a check to see if the property exists:

```js
var x = [];
x[0] = "some value";
x[5] = "another value"
$.each(x, function(index, value) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        console.log(index + " - " + value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```